# Constant gets nil value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, null, nsurlsession

Does anybody know why let data becomes nil, and i get the message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" after i've run the following function?

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let codexxx = String(strData)
        let serverResponse = ServerResponseHandler()
        let number =  serverResponse.removeCodeFromXML(codexxx)
        let data = number.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        self.posts = []
        self.parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
        self.parser.delegate = self

        print ("NUMBER: \(number)")

        let success:Bool = self.parser.parse()
        if success {
            print("parse success!")
           } else {
            print("parse failure!")
        }
        print("Response!: \(strData)")
    })
    task.resume()  
}
```

Do i need to close to close the object or function after it been run? Im really clueless here.

Comment: on which line you get error ? can you log it ?

Comment: what is the response of `        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!`

Comment: The `completionHandler` has an `error` parameter. Before processing the `data` parameter **always** check if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` parameter of the completionHandler has optional type `NData?` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:)), so probably you need to check if it is not nil before unwrapping the optional with `!` or do something like that:

```
...
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    if let data = data, strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let codexxx = String(strData)
        // ... continue here
    } else {
        // there were no data received (either data or strData is nil) 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time a connection fails, you'll get a nil data object.  You should always check to see if A. there is an error object, and B. the response's status code is 200.  If there's an error, or if the status code isn't 200, you probably don't even need to look at the data.